# JavaScript escape sequence

Tags: javascript, java, escaping

I am currently trying to translate a short bit of JavaScript code into Java. 
But since I never did anything with JavaScript, I have trouble translating this line:

```
key += "\x720\\x78X";
```

Can someone help me understanding or translating this?

Comment: `URLDecoder.decode(key, "UTF-8"); `

Comment: Sorry I don't quite get how that helps me. I just want to translate the line above to a proper Java line.

Comment: You can try using `decodeURI`. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/zxeoy00k/).

Comment: According to Google this is a javascript method. But I want an equivalent Java line for key += "\x720\\x78X";

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, it is hard to say because that line seems incorrect: it is trying to append characters to the existing value stored in `key` by using [Hexadecimal escape sequences](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes#hexadecimal), but only 2 digits are allowed in a hex sequence, so `"\x720\\x78X"` is translated to `"r0\x78X"`:

`"\x72"` is `"r"`
then, you have `"0"`,
then there is a escaped inversed slash `"\\"`, that means `"\"`
and then you have `"x78X"`

If you write `"\x72\x78"` you will obtain `"rx"`

I hope this helps you to understand that piece of code...